# intellij idea 14 cannot connect to debug tomcat7 service

Tags: tomcat7, remote-debugging, intellij-14

Ok, I think I tried everything before I am posting this question. Please tell me, what I am (Still) missing. I keep getting "unable to connect" exception (unable to connect hostname:6012), I changed from default port 1099 and it still didn't help.

```
version of IntelliJ 14.0.2
Tomcat 7.0.52
```

Tomcat is running as a service so, I configured on the UI interface of tomcat.exe (java tab) the following JAVA_OPTs

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=57497,server=y,suspend=n
-javaagent:C:\Users\username\.IntelliJIdea14\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6012
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat 7.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat 7.0
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

I made sure the port 57497 is open (open the firewall and telnet).

And on IntelliJ, I made a remote server connection. Please find attached 
pictures. Both intellij and tomcat are running on the same system. I have a static dns setup. sometimes i get connection timedout exception.

[server tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRODc.png)

[connection tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiCfR.png)

Comment: Ok, answering my own question .. i had used the 'remote' config, instead of tomcat - remote config. and then host i had to change from dns name to 127.0.0.1. not sure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my config.

Tomcat JAVA_OPTs to enable remote debugging:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5007

In IntelliJ, I don't use the Configuration-Type 'Tomcat'. In my case 'Remote' works pretty well (I would post an image but I ain't got 10 reputation...). You only need to configure your host and port on the config sheet.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned.. and i still get this --> Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect". for what ever reason intellij puts this as default. -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=57497  instead of  -Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=57497,server=y,suspend=n and its a non editable field

Comment: sorry, i cant upvote you. not enough credential. but your answer did help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use IntelliJ 14.0.3 and I had the same issue, though with Jetty. Switching to using the `remote` instead of `jetty -> remote` worked. I'm guessing they're both supposed to work differently. I just haven't figured out why there are two different options to remote debug.